# why does canvas object keep blinking during animation?

Tags: object, animation, canvas, settimeout

I made an animation in javascript for a house with rising smoke. the smoke is 3 functions for each part of the smoke that flow upwards from the chimney. they are controlled by a slider that toggles the speed at which the smoke exists the chimney. Everything works except when the slider is toggled left to right, the smoke blinks while rising. Could anyone tell me why that is?

Thanks

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Carrey, Justin, Myshkin, Rost</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>

</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500">Get a new Browser!</canvas>

    <script src="script.js" ></script>

    <form>
    <input type="range" min="10" max="250" value="100" id="speedCont"/>
    <p>
        Rostislav Myshkin A00787633 rmyshkin@my.bcit.ca
        <br />
        Completed:3-D house, smoke, animation for smoke, slider for speed.
        <br />
        Challanges: animating the smoke.
    </p>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

javascript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.lineWidth = 4;
ctx.strokeLinecap = 'round';
var a = 1;
var speed = 100;
var posY = 100,
posY2 = 120,
posY3 = 140,
posX = 100,
vx = 5,
vy = 5;


function foundation() {

    //grass
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(25, 375);
    ctx.lineTo(125, 325);
    ctx.lineTo(471, 325);
    ctx.lineTo(400, 375);
    ctx.lineTo(25, 375);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();

    //front face ground
    ctx.fillStyle = "#873600";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(25, 375); //top left
    ctx.lineTo(25, 425); //bottom left
    ctx.lineTo(400, 425); //bottom right
    ctx.lineTo(400, 375); //top right
    ctx.lineTo(25, 375); //top line
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();

    //east face ground 
    ctx.fillStyle = "#872000";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(475, 325); //top right
    ctx.lineTo(475, 375); //bottom right
    ctx.lineTo(400, 425); //bottom line
    ctx.lineTo(400, 375); //top left
    ctx.lineTo(475, 325); //top right
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();

}

function house() {

    //front face
    ctx.fillStyle = "#2980B9";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(110, 365);
    ctx.lineTo(110, 200);
    ctx.lineTo(375, 200);
    ctx.lineTo(375, 365);
    ctx.lineTo(110, 365);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();

    //east face
    ctx.fillStyle = "#1760B4";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(375, 200); //lower left
    ctx.lineTo(415, 180); //
    ctx.lineTo(415, 340);
    ctx.lineTo(375, 365);
    ctx.lineTo(375, 200);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();

    //roof front face 
    ctx.fillStyle = "#B41717";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(95, 210);
    ctx.lineTo(160, 140);
    ctx.lineTo(395, 140);
    ctx.lineTo(365, 210);
    ctx.lineTo(365, 210);
    ctx.lineTo(95, 210);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();

    //roof east face 
    ctx.fillStyle = "darkred";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(365, 210);
    ctx.lineTo(425, 190);
    ctx.lineTo(395, 140);
    ctx.lineTo(365, 210);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();

    //door 
    ctx.fillStyle = "darkred";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(300, 365);
    ctx.lineTo(300, 295);
    ctx.lineTo(250, 295);
    ctx.lineTo(250, 365);
    ctx.lineTo(300, 365);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();

    //doorknob
    ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(290, 335, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();

    //walkway
    ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(250, 365); //left point
    ctx.lineTo(240, 375); //left side
    ctx.lineTo(290, 375);
    ctx.lineTo(300, 365);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();

    //window living room
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(143, 347);
    ctx.lineTo(143, 295);
    ctx.lineTo(212, 295);
    ctx.lineTo(212, 347);
    ctx.lineTo(143, 347);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();

    //window top left
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(143, 275);
    ctx.lineTo(143, 225);
    ctx.lineTo(212, 225);
    ctx.lineTo(212, 275);
    ctx.lineTo(143, 275);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();

    //window top right
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(263, 275);
    ctx.lineTo(263, 225);
    ctx.lineTo(332, 225);
    ctx.lineTo(332, 275);
    ctx.lineTo(263, 275);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();

    //chimney front
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(170, 130); //top left
    ctx.lineTo(170, 180); //left side line
    ctx.lineTo(200, 180); //bottom line
    ctx.lineTo(200, 130); //right side line
    ctx.lineTo(170, 130); //top side line
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();

    //chimney east
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(200, 130); //top left
    ctx.lineTo(215, 123); //top side line
    ctx.lineTo(215, 170); //right side line
    ctx.lineTo(200, 180); //
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();

    //chimney top
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(170, 130); //top left
    ctx.lineTo(185, 122); //left side
    ctx.lineTo(210, 122); //top side
    ctx.lineTo(200, 130); 
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();

}

function smoke1(){

    posY += -vy;
    posX += vx;

    if (posY < -15) posY = 100;  

        ctx.fillStyle = "aqua";
        ctx.fillRect(0,0, 220, 127);

        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(200, posY, 15, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
        ctx.fill();

}   
function smoke2(){

    posY2 += -vy;
    posX += vx;

    if (posY2 < -13) posY2 = 110;



        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(185, posY2, 10, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
        ctx.fill();
}
function smoke3(){

    posY3 += -vy;
    posX += vx;

    if (posY3 < -13) posY3 = 110;



        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5s)";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(210, posY3, 6, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
        ctx.fill();
}

function animate() {
    smoke1();

    var speed = document.getElementById('speedCont').value;

    window.setTimeout(animate, speed);  

}  
function animate2() {
    smoke2();

    var speed = document.getElementById('speedCont').value;

    window.setTimeout(animate2, speed); 

}  
function animate3() {
    smoke3();

    var speed = document.getElementById('speedCont').value;

    window.setTimeout(animate3, speed); 

}  
/**   if (a == 1) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 260, 105);
        smoke();
        a++;
    } else if (a == 2) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 260, 105);
        smokeMed();
        a++;
    } else if (a == 3) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 260, 105);
        smokeBig();
        a = 1;
    } else {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 260, 105);
    }
    window.setTimeout(animate2, speed);
}
**/

window.onload = function all() {

    foundation();
    house();
    animate();
    animate2();
    animate3();
}

window.addEventListener("load", all, false);
//window.setInterval(animate2, 1000);
//window.setTimeout(animate2, speed);
```

css:

```
#canvas {
    background-color: aqua;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 10px ;
}
body {
    background-color: gray;
}

input[type=range] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: 3px solid black;
    width: 500px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    width: 500px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #ddd;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: 3px solid black;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: red;
    margin-top: -8px;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
    outline: none;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The flickr has to do with having multiple `setTimeout` functions. Since you delete the previous state of the smoke on `smoke1()`, once you change the speed there is going to be a discrepancy. If you use only one setTimeout it should work fine in your particular case. Here a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/c5tnpj6y/) as an example.

Answer (score 0):

### Backbuffers & requestAnimationFrame

All rendering to the DOM is double buffered. Rendering is always done to the backBuffer, it is not drawn to the screen. Presenting to the screen should be done when the scene is fully rendered.

When a function exits (returns to idle) the DOM assumes that you have completed all the rendering and what to display the results. This is when the backbuffer is moved to where the screen can see it.

If you have only rendered part of the scene and exit the DOM does not know you have not yet finished rendering and will present the backbuffer as is. The screen refreshes at a much slower rate than you can write to the backbuffer. When the DOM presents the backbuffer to the screen the display hardware may be at any point of scanning out the pixels onto the display hardware. The result is inconsistent flickering and shearing.

You can fix the problem by using only one function to do all the rendering. The problem still will be that when the function exits it may be at any point of the display scan. You will still get some shearing.

To keep in sync with the display hardware and prevent any flickering and shearing use `requestAnimationFrame` (there are endless answers about it in SO) to do all your rendering.

The DOM treats all callback functions called by `requestAnimationFrame` as special and will delay any DOM visual changes being moved from the backbuffer to the screen until the display hardware is in its vertical refresh phase. At that point all changes since the last vertical refresh are moved from back buffers to the screen. (This applies to all visual FX not just the canvas).

**Fixing your code**

As you want a fixed update speed.

```
var speed = 100;
var nextUpdateTime;
function updateAll(time){
    if(nextUpdateTime=== undefined){
       nextUpdateTime= time - speed; // first update now
    }
    if(time >= nextUpdateTime){
       nextUpdateTime= time + (speed - (time - nextUpdateTime)); // get time of next update
       smoke1();
       smoke2();
       smoke3()
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(updateAll);
}
requestAnimationFrame(updateAll);
```

If you want each FX to have its own speed you will have to create a array of speed and nextUpdateTime values. Requested animation frames generally run at 60fps. Time is always the first argument of the requested callback function.

**Better yet run at 60fps**

I would suggest that rather than use a slow update speed (100ms is 10fps) you modify your code to slow the animation down so that it runs smoothly when sped up to 60fps

The following will modify your animation to play the same but at a higher frame rate.

```
var speed = 100;    // the old frame update delay
var frameRate = 60; // requestAnimationFrame frame rate

// vx and vy where the update delta move vectors for the smoke
// that need to be adjusted for the new frame rate.
vx = (vx * (1000 / speed)) / frameRate;
vy = (vy * (1000 / speed)) / frameRate;
function updateAll(time){
    smoke1();
    smoke2();
    smoke3()
    requestAnimationFrame(updateAll);
}
requestAnimationFrame(updateAll);
```

> **NOTE** if you present a lot of rendering work the browser may not be able to keep up. If it cant do it in 1/60th of a second and it will not display anything until the next vertical refresh the frame rate will drop from 60fps to 30fps. 
>   If you suspect this will happen then you should monitor the time between frames and use that to calculate the new smoke position every frame.